# Integral of exponential function with squares

Tags: calculus, integration

> (a) Show that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}=\left(\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-x^2}\right)^2$$ provided that the first integral exists.
>
> (b) Show that the first integral exists, and evaluate it.

Really don't see any way to integrate these functions. Looks beyond normal integration techniques.

**EDIT**: From Marty Cohen's hint, I did part (b) by changing to polar coordinates. The integral becomes $2\pi\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}rdr$, which can be integrated. What about part (a)?

Comment: This is a standard trick for this, and only this (except for a set of functions of measure zero) integral. Convert the first integral to polar form, where $r^2 = x^2+y^2$. Or look it up.

Comment: @martycohen Okay thanks, I'll try that. Still, what about part (a)?

Comment: For part (a), first note $e^{-(x^2+y^)} = e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}$ and then see what general statments can be made about expressions like $\int \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x) g(y) \ dx \ dy$.

Comment: Your integrals are missing the differentials $dx$ and $dy$.  If you had included them, you might have had less trouble with part (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments by [Mike](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530449/integral-of-exponential-function-with-squares#comment1133442_530449) and [marty cohen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530449/integral-of-exponential-function-with-squares#comment1133424_530449):

(a) Since $e^{-(x^2+y^2)} = e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}$, Fubini's theorem implies 
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy = \int_{\mathbb R}e^{-x^2}\,dx\,\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-y^2}\,dy$$
Both integrals on the right are equal, since the name of the variable of integration does not matter.

(b) Use polar  coordinates: 
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy = 2\pi \int_0^\infty  re^{-r^2}\,dr
= -\pi   e^{-r^2}\bigg|_0^\infty   =\pi$$